# how to backup and restore kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I'm making an alarm app and
I want to back up the room database by creating a .json file, and then restore it when I decide (when I restore it, it schedules the registered alarms).
The problem is the permissions that I'm not comfortable with (especially on Android 13 or more)

```
`    // Exportar dados para JSON e salvar em um arquivo
    fun exportDataToJson(context: Context) {
        CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
            val db = AppDatabase.getDatabase(context)

            val remedio = db.remedioDao().getRemedio()
            val alarmeRemedio = db.alarmeDao().getAllAlarme()
            val itemAlarmeRemedio = db.itemAlarmeDao().getAllItemAlarme()

            val dataToExport = mapOf(
                "remedio" to remedio,
                "alarmeRemedio" to alarmeRemedio,
                "itemAlarmeRemedio" to itemAlarmeRemedio
            )
            val json = Gson().toJson(dataToExport)

            val directory = File("/storage/emulated/0/Download/room_backups")
            if (!directory.exists()) {
                directory.mkdirs()
            }

            val file = File("/storage/emulated/0/Download/room_backups/my_remedio.json")
            if (!file.exists()) {
                file.createNewFile()
            }

            val backupDir = File(
                Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS),
                "room_backups"
            )

            val backupFile = File(backupDir, "my_remedio.json")
            Log.d("Backup", "Caminho do diretório: ${backupDir.absolutePath}")

            FileWriter(backupFile).use { fileWriter ->
                try {
                    fileWriter.write(json)
                    Log.d("Backup", "Escrita no arquivo de backup concluída.")
                    withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                        Toast.makeText(
                            requireContext(),
                            "Backup concluído com sucesso.",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                        ).show()
                    }
                } catch (e: Exception) {
                    Log.e("Backup", "Erro ao escrever no arquivo de backup: ${e.message}")
                    withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                        Toast.makeText(
                            requireContext(),
                            "Erro ao salvar o backup.",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                        )
                            .show()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }


    fun restoreFromJson(context: Context, jsonFileName: String) {
        var json = ""
        try {
            Log.d("Restore", "Caminho do arquivo JSON: $jsonFileName")
            json = File(jsonFileName).bufferedReader().use { it.readText() }
            // Restante do código para processar o JSON
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Log.e("Restore", "Erro ao ler o arquivo JSON: ${e.message}")
            e.printStackTrace()
        }

        val gson = Gson()
        val jsonObject = JsonParser.parseString(json).asJsonObject
        // Agora, você pode acessar as propriedades como um objeto JSON
        val remedios: List<RemedioVo> = gson.fromJson(
            jsonObject.getAsJsonArray("remedio"),
            object : TypeToken<List<RemedioVo>>() {}.type
        )
        val alarmes: List<AlarmeRemedioVo> = gson.fromJson(
            jsonObject.getAsJsonArray("alarmeRemedio"),
            object : TypeToken<List<AlarmeRemedioVo>>() {}.type
        )
        val itensAlarme: List<ItemAlarmeRemedioVo> = gson.fromJson(
            jsonObject.getAsJsonArray("itemAlarmeRemedio"),
            object : TypeToken<List<ItemAlarmeRemedioVo>>() {}.type
        )

        this.database = AppDatabase.getDatabase(context)
        this.remedioDao = this.database.remedioDao()
        this.alarmeDao = this.database.alarmeDao()
        this.itemAlarmeDao = this.database.itemAlarmeDao()

        // Limpar e inserir os dados para cada entidade
        CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {

            try {
                database.remedioDao().apply {
                    deleteAllRemedios()
                    insertAllRemedios(remedios)
                }
                database.alarmeDao().apply {
                    deleteAllAlarmes()
                    insertAllAlarmes(alarmes)
                }
                database.itemAlarmeDao().apply {
                    deleteAllItensAlarme()
                    insertAllItensAlarme(itensAlarme)
                }
                val data = Date().time

                val itemAlarmeRemedio = database.itemAlarmeDao().getAllItemAlarmeMais(data)

                //falta excluir  o alarme
                //redefinir os alarmes
                withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                    //cancelar todos os alarme cancelAll() so funciona para versao 34
                    for (i in itemAlarmeRemedio.indices) {
                        var alarmeRemedio: AlarmeRemedioVo? = null
                        CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
                            alarmeRemedio = database.alarmeDao()
                                .getRemedio(itemAlarmeRemedio[i].fk_alertaRemedio.toLong())

                        }

                        val alarmManager = context.getSystemService(AlarmManager::class.java)
                        val intent = Intent(context, AlarmReceiverNovo::class.java).apply {
                            putExtra("id", itemAlarmeRemedio[i].id)
                            putExtra("remedio", alarmeRemedio)
                        }

                        val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                            context,
                            itemAlarmeRemedio[i].id!!,
                            intent,
                            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT or PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE
                        )

                        alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent)
                    }


                    //for para definir o alarme
                    for (i in itensAlarme.indices) {
                        if (itensAlarme[i].dataAlarme > data) {
                            var alarmeRemedioVo: AlarmeRemedioVo? = null
                            for (a in alarmes.indices) {
                                if (alarmes[a].id == itensAlarme[i].fk_alertaRemedio) {
                                    alarmeRemedioVo = alarmes[a]
                                }
                            }
                            //definindo o alarme
                            val alarmManager =
                                requireContext().getSystemService(AlarmManager::class.java)
                            val intent =
                                Intent(requireContext(), AlarmReceiverNovo::class.java).apply {
                                    putExtra("id", itensAlarme[i].id)
                                    putExtra("remedio", alarmeRemedioVo)
                                }
                            alarmManager.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(
                                AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                                itensAlarme[i].dataAlarme,
                                PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                                    requireContext(),
                                    itensAlarme[i].id!!,
                                    intent,
                                    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT or PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE
                                )
                            )
                        }

                    }// fim for para definir o alarme


                    Toast.makeText(
                        requireContext(),
                        "Restauração concluído com sucesso.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                    ).show()
                }

            } catch (_: Exception) {
                withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                    Toast.makeText(
                        requireContext(),
                        "Erro ao Restaurar o backup.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                    ).show()
                }
            }
        }// CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch

    }`
```

I just need to know how to grant permissions to create, write and read the file.